# Jest module import only fails in debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

Using VsCode and jest test runner I can successfully "run" tests but when I try to "debug" them they fail because:

```
  Cannot find module 'components/Modal' from 'src/components/Button.js'
```

Although the above works when compiled/run etc. So it doesnt understand it should start in root when looking for this file.

So in my config I have:

```
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src', '<rootDir>'],
rootDir: '../',
roots: ['<rootDir>/src', '<rootDir>/eslint-custom-rules']
```

So is there a separate config for defining the root src in vscode/jest when debugging?

Comment: Looks like, Jest config is ignored when jest debugging in VSCode. I see it doesn't take into account `transformIgnorePatterns` set in Jest config.